# maven-ear-plugin <packagingIncludes> not including project files

Tags: java, maven, ear, maven-ear-plugin

My ear project has the following structure:

[image]

And my pom.xml goes like this:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
      <earSourceIncludes>META-INF/*</earSourceIncludes>
      <packagingIncludes>META-INF/*,**/*.war</packagingIncludes>
      <version>7</version>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>com.ex</groupId>
                        <artifactId>one</artifactId>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
      <generateApplicationXml>false</generateApplicationXml>  
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

What I want is to include in my ear file the contents of the folder META-INF, in a similar folder in the root of the ear file called META-INF.

I've tried multiple combinations with earSourceIncludes and packagingIncludes with no success: My ear file has the linked application .war, which is good, and a META-INF folder which doesn't have what I need, but a pregenerated MANIFEST.MF file and a maven folder with the pom instead.

I wonder if I need the earSourceIncludes at all. To be honest, I don't know why it didn't work with just the packagingIncludes parameter.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand, but the META-INF folder is outside of src folder and I don't think the plugin will pick it up. I think that if you put META-INF in src/main/resources folder it should work without packagingIncludes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `maven-resource-plugin` to include the content of META-INF folder to root META-INF folder. See below.

Let

Project base directory - `${project.basedir}`

EAR root directory - `${project.rootdir}`

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <!-- here the phase you need -->
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>                         
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/META-INF</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>                      
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/META-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and give feedback

Comment: Update: The idea to combine ear plugin with resources plugin was on spot so I'll mark the answer as correct, but the output directory project.basedir wouldn't include my files in the ear since apparently the ear plugin takes them from the build directory (/target). So I had to use ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/META-INF, and its working fine. For further readers, it probably depends on how you configure the ear plugin.

Comment: @Jorge.V Thanks for letting me know about that. I had only a little experience with ear plugin.